# Facebook Linter returns 'Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.'

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-graph-api, scrape

facebook returns "Error Parsing URL:    Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped." when I use Facebook Linter. I already tried taking away the meta tags then putting them back in. I can't get this to work please help.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.eyp.ph%2Fmoms

Comment: It's taking me over 10 seconds to get a reply from your server.  Perhaps the ̶L̶i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶ Debugger is simply timing out when trying to retrieve your URL.

Comment: You should try to create a stripped down minimal page containing only the required `og:tags` and testing it with the Debugger.

Comment: there is no meta tags i found only one there,,,but you need to keep in mind that the og:properties should not be kept dynamically and it be kept as static ready while scraping !

Comment: It turned out that I had a slow SQL query that caused facebook to timeout. Thank you Lix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had a slow SQL query that caused a slow first byte when loading. That caused facebook to timeout. Thank you Lix.